# openFDA Device Adverse Events missing for Dec, 2015 (as of 19-Jan-2016)

Tags: openfda

There still appears to be a problem with the data for Dec, 2015... the following query returns zero results as of now:
http://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20151201+TO+20151231]

Answer (score 2):

The data that powers that particular API is only available on a quarterly basis and is **currently only available through Q3 of 2015**.

http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/Surveillance/AdverseDrugEffects/ucm082193.htm

Even though the data is released on a **quarterly basis**, the pipeline that updates the `/drug/event.json` endpoint is run on a **weekly basis** in order to update the `openfda` section of all the documents, since the `openfda` section's data sources update cycles are more frequent.

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks for you using the openFDA.

Comment: The information you mentioned is for Drug related Adverse Events, I am referring to the Device Adverse Events.  The Device related data is current through end of November, 2015 and for the last few months has been updated Monthly, usually within the first two weeks of the following month.  For example, the following query for November data returns 57,919 results:
http://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5b20151101+TO+20151130%5d